# preg_match for matching strings like "max_length[:num:]"

Tags: php

I have some strings like `max_length[:num:]`where `:num:` can be any number ie(`max_length[50]` or `max_length[100]` etc).

What will be the preg_match code for such strings in PHP?

Comment: @Hnatt: Vote on the question, not the problem.

Comment: I did. Just explained to Pawan why he got -1 for this question. SO recommends to add comments if I downvote so that the asking person knew why he is being downvoted.

Comment: {sarcasm}Heaven forbid someone should ask a question on a Q&A site.{/sarcasm}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
'/max_length\[(\d+)\]/'
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits.

If your string must contain only this, use this one instead:

```
'/^max_length\[(\d+)\]$/'
```

You can use it like this:

```
$string = 'max_length[123]';
if (preg_match('/max_length\[(\d+)\]/', $string, $match)) {
    $number = $match[1];
}
```

Try it here: http://ideone.com/a9Cux

Comment: You probably want to use single quotes. Just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
/max_length\[([0-9]+)\]/
```

//EDIT
As Tomalak Geret'kal noted, this will match also strings like:

```
aaa_max_length[100]
```

If you want to match only strings like $foo = 'max_length[100]', your regexp shall be:

```
/^max_length\[([0-9]+)\]$/
```

Comment: Don't forget your start and end anchors.

Comment: Edited to include your advice

Comment: And thanks for including delimiters. So many people don't seem to want to bother >.<